# Effect of power outage on power supply connected to surge arrester and voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, power, power-management

I have a computer that connected to an automatic voltage regulator and an a surge arrester. The power supply unit is set to automatic power recovery so that when there's an outage, it will start the machine when the power goes back on. I have surge arrester installed so that when there is a power back on after the outage, it will protect it from the voltage spike and its induction. Also the voltage regulator protects it from the voltage instability during normal operation.

The question is: is this kind of setup enough to protect the power supply unit from the surge of the outage? I don't use UPS since I figure it out, the machine doesn't do any kind of writing to the hard drive.

Comment: "the machine doesn't do any kind of writing to the hard drive." Really? That doesn't make sense. Most computers are reading/wring to disk drives all the time.

Comment: it does mostly memory swapping, but it doesn't write data to permanent disk. Mostly it does operation to cloud service

Comment: It will still be reading/writing a swap file.

Comment: what is the worst scenario when it is doing something to the swap file, then the machine shuts down ungracefully?

Comment: Sudden loss of power can cause disk failure.

Comment: is it gonna be a permanent damage, though?

Comment: You asked for the worst case scenario, so yes.